# Request a more specific item in a list python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to act on a set of data which has been delivered to me in a format like this

```
[['Start', 'a', 1, 'B'],
 ['West', 1],
 ['West', 7],
 ['East', 2],
 ['West', 6],
 ['South',1],
 ['West', 0],
```

I can save this information to a variable called steps when I try to print index 1 on steps I receive this output " ['Start', 'a', 1, 'B'] "
What I would like to print is only 'a' how can I achieve this?

Raw data generates the above data output, creating a random start and specifying a direction and number
Here is my code sample

```
"from data_generator import raw_data
steps = (raw_data())

print(steps[0])
```

To be clear the output I receive when I input this is

```
[['Start', 'a', 1, 'B'],
```

I would like to receive

```
['a']
```

Apologies if this is unclear I am new to stack

Comment: Do you understand *why* `steps[0]` is `['Start','a',1,'8']`?

Comment: `steps[0][1]` should give it to you. Essentially, this is known as a _multi-dimensional_ array -- `steps[0]` returns the array element with the 4 things in it, but then you can use array access again to get the item you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you print `steps[0]`, you are referencing the first list in the "list of lists", so when you need to return an item in a certain index of that list you reference, you can just use the same syntax that you regularly use to call a specific item from a list. So all you need to do is `steps[0][1]`